# sending an email by using webmail through nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

iam using nodemailer to sent an email but it only working for email not for gmail

// this is config connections

```
"nodemailer" : { 
         
         "host": "xxx.xxxxx.com",
         "port": 587,
         "secure":true,
        "auth": {
        "user": "myuser.com", 
        "pass": "password"
    } ,
    "tls": {
      "rejectUnauthorized": false,
      "minVersion": "TLSv1"
       },
    "debug":true,
    "logger":true
  },
  "receivingEmail": {
    "feedbackemail" : "abcd@gmailcom",
    "contactemail" : "abcdef@gmail.com"
  }
```

//nodemailer configurations

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport((config["nodemailer"]));
      var mailOptions = {
                from: `${config["nodemailer"]["user"]}`,
                to: tomail,
                subject: subject ,
                text: data
              };
              transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error,"17");
                } else {
                  console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
                }
              });

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          } 
        });
```

here iam sending an email but couldn't able to send gmail accounts
[Nodemailer 6.1.1 not working with NodeJs >=12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228558/nodemailer-6-1-1-not-working-with-nodejs-12)
i tried this.. could you suggest me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make these changes to the gmail account to send an email. Go [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and change it ON because Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes your account more vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps, which we recommend, or turn on access if you want to use them despite the risks.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196467/sending-email-via-node-js-using-nodemailer-is-not-working) thread have some options which you can try and might help if the above solution doesn't work.